# Is Minecraft available for Linux?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

Is Minecraft available for Linux?

If so, where can I buy it and download it?

Comment: You mean apart from buying it from the [offical Minecraft website](https://minecraft.net/store)?

Comment: While colorfusion's answer is correct, have you tried anything to solve this problem for yourself? A simple google search *minecraft on linux* returns **thousands** of tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Log into [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/) and visit the "Download" page.

On there, you should be able to download a Minecraft.jar file (If you don't see it by default, click "Show all platforms" first).

You will need to make sure you have a Java runtime environment installed in order to run it.

Answer (score -3):

You can go on minecraft.net, log in, select platforms, and download demo or buy it.